ag-grid select cell does not display the entire content of select cell dropdown popup
After upgrading from V22 to V28, the dropdowns do not display the complete content of the select cell as the previous version did.
before (ag grid V19 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-button-renderer-dropdown-zbbyan?file=package.json):

after (ag grid V8 https://stackblitz.com/edit/finitelooper-ng16-dmbxnj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Is there any additional styling that needs to be applied to achieve this?
thanks

What bootstrap version you are using?

@AshishRatan ngx-bootstrap 11.0.2

First of all you are trying to compare 2 different things in term of functionality.
one is using cell renderer, second is example of cell editing.

good spot. I've updated the column definitions from the V28 project to the V18 and it looks perfect on the V18, unlike the select cell from V28.

still you are mixing two things,
One thing you can do is to change double click enable to single click. easy to do in ag-grid editing ,
Second, the dropdown needs to be fixed from styling,
third use same themes to replicate same effect
